MSVC .dll build FAILED without indication as to why (fails only for vcpkg port)
I have a C++ library that builds successfully using Visual Studio 2022 (MSVC 17.6) in both Release and Debug configurations.  It also builds successfully without any warnings using WSL (Ubuntu 20.04.6 / g++ 10.5.0).
I've recently created a vcpkg custom-overlay port to test packaging this project as we are moving towards a public release (this project is unfortunately not publicly available yet so I cannot share the entire source).  This port builds and installs successfully for linux, and it builds the windows debug configuration fine, but it fails for the windows release configuration.
The command I am using is:
.\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe install vira --overlay-ports .\source\repos\custom-overlay\

And this is the output:
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    vira:x64-windows@0.8.0 -- C:\Users\cgnam\.\source\repos\custom-overlay\vira
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
Compiler found: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
Restored 0 package(s) from C:\Users\cgnam\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 218 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/1 vira:x64-windows@0.8.0...
Building vira:x64-windows@0.8.0...
C:\Users\cgnam\.\source\repos\custom-overlay\vira: info: installing overlay port from here
-- Using cached C:/Users/cgnam/vcpkg/downloads/vira-77f084234d7f87b7d65d3139423716a2a8699062.tar.gz
-- Extracting source C:/Users/cgnam/vcpkg/downloads/vira-77f084234d7f87b7d65d3139423716a2a8699062.tar.gz
-- Using source at C:/Users/cgnam/vcpkg/buildtrees/vira/src/a2a8699062-36622b99f2.clean
-- Found external ninja('1.11.0').
-- Configuring x64-windows
-- Building x64-windows-dbg
-- Building x64-windows-rel
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:134 (message):
    Command failed: C:/Users/cgnam/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.29.2-windows/cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe --build . --config Release --target install -- -v -j13
    Working Directory: C:/Users/cgnam/vcpkg/buildtrees/vira/x64-windows-rel
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\buildtrees\vira\install-x64-windows-rel-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_build.cmake:74 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_install.cmake:16 (vcpkg_cmake_build)
  C:/Users/cgnam/source/repos/custom-overlay/vira/portfile.cmake:12 (vcpkg_cmake_install)
  scripts/ports.cmake:192 (include)


error: building vira:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED

When I go to the specified install-x64-windows-rel-out.log file, everything looks fine until the very end when it seemingly fails out of nowehere with no cause I can identify:
[47/48] C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\downloads\tools\cmake-3.29.2-windows\cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386\bin\cmake.exe -E __create_def C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\buildtrees\vira\x64-windows-rel\source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\.\exports.def C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\buildtrees\vira\x64-windows-rel\source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\.\exports.def.objs && cd C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\buildtrees\vira\x64-windows-rel" && C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\downloads\tools\cmake-3.29.2-windows\cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_dll --intdir=source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe  source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\color.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\pose.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rigid_body.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rotation.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\cameras\camera.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\cameras\pinhole_camera.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\cameras\blender_camera.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\cameras\sensor.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\dems\spc_maplet.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\interfaces\obj_interface.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\interfaces\ply_interface.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\interfaces\dsk_interface.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\mesh.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\triangle.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\vertex.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\images\interfaces\image_interface.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\images\image_utils.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\images\image.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\images\image_to_imagebuf.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\lights\light.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\lights\point_light.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\lights\sphere_light.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\cook_torrance.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\ggx.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\lambertian.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\material.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\mcewen.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\quipu\class_ids.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\quipu\quipu_reader.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\quipu\quipu_writer.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\quipu\quipu_io.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\aabb.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\vira_bvh.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\vira_embree.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\nodes.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\tlas.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\cpu_path_tracer.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\cpu_rasterizer.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\ray.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\renderer.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\scene\scene.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\scene\scene_graph.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\utils\utils.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\utils\spice_utils.cpp.obj  /out:vira.dll /implib:source\vira\vira.lib /pdb:vira.pdb /dll /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /nologo /DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF    /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DEF:source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\.\exports.def  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\tinyobjloader.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\lz4.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\tbb12.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\tbbmalloc.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\geotiff_i.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\proj.lib  external\glob\glob.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\miniply.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\OpenImageIO.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\cspice.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\glm.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\embree3.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\tiff.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\OpenImageIO_Util.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\Imath-3_1.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
FAILED: vira.dll source/vira/vira.lib 
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\downloads\tools\cmake-3.29.2-windows\cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386\bin\cmake.exe -E __create_def C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\buildtrees\vira\x64-windows-rel\source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\.\exports.def C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\buildtrees\vira\x64-windows-rel\source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\.\exports.def.objs && cd C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\buildtrees\vira\x64-windows-rel" && C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\downloads\tools\cmake-3.29.2-windows\cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_dll --intdir=source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe  source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\color.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\pose.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rigid_body.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rotation.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\cameras\camera.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\cameras\pinhole_camera.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\cameras\blender_camera.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\cameras\sensor.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\dems\spc_maplet.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\interfaces\obj_interface.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\interfaces\ply_interface.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\interfaces\dsk_interface.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\mesh.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\triangle.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\geometry\vertex.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\images\interfaces\image_interface.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\images\image_utils.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\images\image.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\images\image_to_imagebuf.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\lights\light.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\lights\point_light.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\lights\sphere_light.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\cook_torrance.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\ggx.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\lambertian.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\material.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\materials\mcewen.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\quipu\class_ids.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\quipu\quipu_reader.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\quipu\quipu_writer.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\quipu\quipu_io.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\aabb.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\vira_bvh.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\vira_embree.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\nodes.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\acceleration\tlas.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\cpu_path_tracer.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\cpu_rasterizer.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\ray.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\rendering\renderer.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\scene\scene.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\scene\scene_graph.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\utils\utils.cpp.obj source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\utils\spice_utils.cpp.obj  /out:vira.dll /implib:source\vira\vira.lib /pdb:vira.pdb /dll /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /nologo /DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF    /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DEF:source\vira\CMakeFiles\vira.dir\.\exports.def  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\tinyobjloader.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\lz4.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\tbb12.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\tbbmalloc.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\geotiff_i.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\proj.lib  external\glob\glob.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\miniply.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\OpenImageIO.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\cspice.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\glm.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\embree3.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\tiff.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\OpenImageIO_Util.lib  C:\Users\cgnam\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\Imath-3_1.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I have looked through these multiple times but I cannot identify a reason as to why this would have failed.  Again, everything works perfectly as expected when the port is installed on Linux.  (And both Debug/Release configurations work on Windows when I build the project directly in Visual Studio rather than using the vcpkg install command from the custom-overlay)
This is the porfile.cmake if it is relevant:
vcpkg_from_git(
    OUT_SOURCE_PATH SOURCE_PATH
    URL git@aetd-git.gsfc.nasa.gov:vira/vira.git
    REF 77f084234d7f87b7d65d3139423716a2a8699062 # 0.8.0
    HEAD_REF vcpkg_dev
)

vcpkg_cmake_configure(
    SOURCE_PATH "${SOURCE_PATH}"
)

vcpkg_cmake_install()

vcpkg_cmake_config_fixup(
    PACKAGE_NAME "vira"
    CONFIG_PATH "lib/vira/cmake"
)

# Remove empty directories:
file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/lib/vira")
file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/debug/lib/vira")
file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/debug/include")
file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/debug/share")

file(INSTALL "${SOURCE_PATH}/LICENSE" DESTINATION "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/share/${PORT}" RENAME copyright)
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/usage" "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/share/${PORT}/usage" COPYONLY)

I recognize I have not given a whole lot of information as I cannot share all of the source at this time.  But I don't even know where to begin looking for a problem here.  If anyone has any idea what might be a possible cause, I would very much appreciate any ideas.
EDIT:
I've discovered by forcing my library to build statically by adding:
vcpkg_check_linkage(ONLY_STATIC_LIBRARY)

to the top of the portfile.cmake, that it will build an install correctly for Windows.  So something about being built as a shared library is broken (though again, Visual Studio has no problem building this exact commit as a shared library.  It is only when I attempt to have vcpkg build/install it from the custom-overlay port or private regsitry)

Here's an exercise for you: start removing files until it starts compiling again (if ever). That will help you narrow down either the problem source file, or if you run out of source files, the cmake script itself.

Run each of the commands in the failing step manually and check the result of each of them to narrow down the problem

Bit of a shot in the dark, but is it possible that the vcpkg invocation sometimes pieces together a command line with a path name that's longer than 260 characters? This is a (configurable, but default) hard limit on Windows, and might cause cryptic error like this. Ran into it myself once or twice already, it happens pretty quickly as directory trees grow deeper.

@Blindy I've attempted removing as many of the source files as I could, but the problem persists.  I believe it must be related to the CMakeLists.txt or portfile.cmake in some way, as I don't believe there should be a problem (manually building with Visual Studio works completely fine)

@AlanBirtles I've attempted to do this, but am getting confusing results.  It isn't clear to me how to run individual commands from the generated ninja.build.  When I attempt to run ninja in the vcpkg/buildtrees/vira/x64-windows-rel/ directory, it fails immediately complaining of things like memory and string being missing (which is not the case when vcpkg runs the build process, as that at least builds the debug version of my library (vira.dll) successfully, and builds all of the obj files for all my sources in the release config, just failing to build the final .dll

Though, when I go to the vcpkg/buildtrees/vira/x64-linux-rel in a WSL terminal, clean it, then run either ninja or cmake --build . --install (I've test both) it does build and install correctly.  So perhaps there is something about both the x64-windows-rel/ and x64-windows-dbg/ directories/build.ninja files, or the version of ninja used by vcpkg that I'm not understanding
